# Proof verification of monotonicity of $g(x) = \frac{f(x)}{x}$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

Let $f: [0, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function with $f(0) = 0$. Assume that $f$ is differentiable on $(0, \infty)$, and $f'$ is monotonically increasing. Show that the function $g: (0, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $g(x) = \frac{f(x)}{x}$ is also monotonically increasing.

I am not sure if the following proof is correct, any critique would be appreciated.

To show that $g(x) = \frac{f(x)}{x}$ is monotonically increasing, we need to demonstrate that $g'(x) \geq 0$ for all $x \in (0, \infty)$. Since $f(x)$ is differentiable on $(0, \infty)$, we can use the quotient rule to find the derivative of $g(x)$:

$
g'(x) = \frac{f'(x) \cdot x - f(x) \cdot 1}{x^2}
$

Now, given that $f'(x)$ is monotonically increasing, let's analyze $g'(x)$:

$
g'(x) = \frac{x}{x^2}f'(x) - \frac{f(x)}{x^2} = \frac{1}{x}f'(x) - \frac{f(x)}{x^2}
$

Since $f'(x)$ is monotonically increasing, the term $\frac{1}{x}f'(x)$ is non-negative. Additionally, as $f(x)$ is continuous on $(0, \infty)$ and $f(0) = 0$, the term $\frac{f(x)}{x^2}$ is also non-negative.

Therefore, $g'(x)$ is a sum of non-negative terms, implying $g'(x) \geq 0$ for all $x \in (0, \infty)$. This implies that the function $g(x)$ is monotonically increasing on $(0, \infty)$.

Comment: $f'(x)$ monotonically increasing does not necessarily imply $\frac{1}{x}f'(x)$ is non-negative.

Comment: Also you cannot deduce $\frac{f(x)}{x^2}$ is non-negative from the fact it is continuous and $f(0)=0$.

Comment: You didn't claim that $f(x)$ is increasing in the question - is this the case?

Comment: Okay, I am sorry for the mix up, the question stated that $f'$ is increasing. Thanks for pointing out the flaws in my proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe the statement you are trying to prove is true. Take $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$, then all your conditions are satisfied, but $g(x)=x^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ is not monotonically increasing.